# I am trying to iterate through a struct array, and resume where I left off, when I call that function(for loop) again

Tags: c

So, I am a beginner in C and I am writing a simple I/O Program, I am facing a problem.

I want to store some data in a struct array, and then I want to call that function again, and store data after the data stored earlier. But the issue is when I call the function again and store data, it overwrites the old data stored.

Example:

If the user wants to enter e.g. 3 entries first and another 2 entries the next time, the first 3 should be stored in `stock_[0]`...`stock_[2]` and the next 2 in `stock_[3]` and `stock_[4]` etc.

Here is my code. I have tried to use `static int i`; as iteration counter but that didn't help either.

This is the struct:

```
struct stock{
    char item_name[100];
    float item_rate;
    int item_quantity;
} stock_[99];
```

This is the Code:

```
choice_1:
    printf("\n\n\t\t===================================");
    printf("\n\t\tHow many Entries you want to make to the stock: ");
    scanf("%d", &entry);
    system("cls");
    for(i=index_stock;i<entry;i++)
    {
        printf("\n\t\tEnter Item - %d Name: ",i+1);
        scanf("%s",stock_[i].item_name);
        printf("\t\tEnter its Rate(price per 1 item): ");
        scanf("%f", &stock_[i].item_rate);
        printf("\t\tEnter its Quantity: ");
        scanf("%d", &stock_[i].item_quantity);
        printf("\t\tStock Updated Successfully!");
        printf("\n\n\t\t===================================");
    }
choice_3:
    printf("\n\n\t\tPress 1 to Add another item to Stock\n\t\tPress 2 to go to Stock Menu\n\t\tPress 3 to go to Main Menu\n\t\tPress 4 to Exit Program\n\t\t->Please make a choice: ");
    int choice_s_;
    scanf("%d", &choice_s_);
    if(choice_s_==1)
    {
        system("cls");
        goto choice_1;
    }
```

So here if I input some data, and then want to input some more data(ie calling the for loop again after it is finished ie

```
if(choice_s_==1)
{
    system("cls");
    goto choice_1; //calling the loop again to input data
}
```

It overwrites the old data. I tried my best to explain my issue, My english is weak so sorry for that

**Edit 1:**
I defined a variable `int index_stock=0;` globally and updated its value at the end of for loop `index_stock=i;`, now the problem is that last data gets overwritten by newly input data instead of the whole data like previously.
Example:
I stored ''Shoes'' and ''Loffers'' the first time, and then when I call it again to store some more data lets say ''Joggers'', then what happens is ''Loffers'' gets overwritten by ''Joggers''. What I mean is that if I print all the data stored, it prints ''Shoes'' and ''Joggers'' Instead of printing ''Shoes'', ''Loffers'' and ''Joggers''

here is the updated code:

```
int index_stock=0; //defined globally so I can access anywhere
```

```
choice_1:
    printf("\n\n\t\t===================================");
    printf("\n\t\tHow many Entries you want to make to the stock: ");
    scanf("%d", &entry);
    system("cls");
    for(i=index_stock;i<entry;i++)
    {
        printf("\n\t\tEnter Item - %d Name: ",i+1);
        scanf("%s",stock_[i].item_name);
        printf("\t\tEnter its Rate(price per 1 item): ");
        scanf("%f", &stock_[i].item_rate);
        printf("\t\tEnter its Quantity: ");
        scanf("%d", &stock_[i].item_quantity);
        printf("\t\tStock Updated Successfully!");
        printf("\n\n\t\t===================================");
        index_stock=i //updated the index_stock with last value of i as suggested by @Andy Newman
    }
choice_3:
    printf("\n\n\t\tPress 1 to Add another item to Stock\n\t\tPress 2 to go to Stock Menu\n\t\tPress 3 to go to Main Menu\n\t\tPress 4 to Exit Program\n\t\t->Please make a choice: ");
    int choice_s_;
    scanf("%d", &choice_s_);
    if(choice_s_==1)
    {
        system("cls");
        goto choice_1;
    }
```

**Edit 2:**
I was updating the index_stock value inside the for loop, took it outside the loop and changed the for loop to(suggested by @Bodo):

```
for (i = index_stock; (i < index_stock + entry) && (i < (sizeof(stock) / sizeof(stock[0]))); i++)
```

And it worked!

Comment: style advice 1: never use a goto statement. Wrap that whole thing in a while(keep_trying) loop or equivalent.

Comment: style advice 2: don't use magic numbers (99). define a constant which is 99 and use that. Otherwise later you will check that it isn't being exceeded, and then change it to 200, and then make a mistake ...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details, maybe add an example. Do I understand correct that you want the following behavior? If the user wants to enter e.g. 3 entries first and another 2 entries the next time, you want to store the first 3 in `stock_[0]`..`stock_[2]` and the next 2 in `stock_[3] and `stock_[4]` etc.

Comment: @Bodo correct, I want to store some data through the iteration and then the next time if I want to add some more data, it shoulnt replace the older data but instead resume from where the last iteration left

Answer (score 0):

your for loop goes from 0 to whatever. Every time. If you want to start somewhere else you need to remember where the somewhere else is, which means you need a variable. There are a lot of options, but experience tells me you should store the length of your array (not the 99, but the number of items actually stored in it).

```
length = 0;
...
for (i=length; ...)
...
length = i;
```

Comment: I suggest to also check the index to prevent out-of-bounds access to the array, e.g. `for (i = length; (i < length + entry) && (i < (sizeof(stock) / sizeof(stock[0]))); i++)`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I made a variable named  ```int index_stock=0``` Then at the end of the for loop I updated its value with ```i``` i-e  ```index_stock=i```
It sort of works but it still replaces the last stored data. For example: If I enter shoes and lofers as first two entries and then after entering some more data like joggers, then the loffers data is replaced by joggers.

Comment: @MakaveliN1 Instead of describing your code changes, please edit your question and **append** your modified code. Don't replace the original code because the answer is based on your original question. Copy&paste enough code, so that we can see where you define the variables `index_stock` and how you use it to access the array. I suggest to add a statement like "Modified code based on Andy Newman's answer:" followed by the modified code and your problem decription including the input you use, the actual result you get and the expected result. Try to create a [mre].

Comment: @Bodo I updated my original post with all the changes I made. Can you please look into it and help me figure out what's wrong still

Comment: @MakaveliN1 The line `index_stock=i //updated the index_stock with last value of i as suggested by @Andy Newman` should be after the end of the `for` loop and see the `for` loop example in my first comment to this answer, i.e. `for (i = index_stock; (i < index_stock + entry) && (i < (sizeof(stock) / sizeof(stock[0]))); i++) { /* ... */ } index_stock=i;`

Comment: @Bodo Thank you, it worked! Updating original Post